# Think python excercise 5.3.2 Returns error

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to solve Think Python's exercise which asks to write a program that will prompt the user to input the size of three sticks in order to calculate if they can make up a triangle. The rule is that if any of the three length of the sticks is greater than the sum of the other two, the triangle cannot be made. What I did is created a pythagorean equation that works when you input the values as a stand alone is_triangle, but when i try to pass the values through triangle_demo() it does not work and returns a error prompt.

```
def is_triangle(a,b,c):
    if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
        print('pythagore checks out')
        return a**2 + b**2 == c**2
    else:
        print('no')


def prompt_input(prompt):
    try:
        ans = (input(int(prompt)))
        return ans
    except ValueError:
            print('value error and stuff')


def triangle_demo():
    print('input dem values')
    a = prompt_input('input side a: ')
    b = prompt_input('input side b: ')
    c = prompt_input('input side c: ')
    return is_triangle(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the logic is wrong in

```
ans = (input(int(prompt)))
```

You should convert the *output* from `input` to a number, but you're trying to convert its prompt to a number instead, which will raise a `ValueError`. Actually, it would be better to convert the input to `float`, rather than `int`; that way, your program will be able to handle triangles with non-integer sides. Also, we can improve `prompt_input` by making it loop until the user provides valid input, rather than returning `None` if the user provides invalid input.

Also, the logic in your `is_triangle` function only tests for right triangles, but it's supposed to test all triangles, not just right triangles. The [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) states that each side must be less than the sum of the other two sides. So, if the 3 sides are a, b, and c, then

```
a < b + c
b < a + c
c < a + b
```

We can simplify this

```
2a < a + b + c
2b < a + b + c
2c < a + b + c
```

In other words, each of a, b, and c must be less than (a + b + c) / 2

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
def is_triangle(*t):
    # Make sure there are 3 sides
    if len(t) != 3:
        return False
    # Make sure that all the sides are positive
    if not all(u > 0 for u in t):
        return False
    # Test that no side is too big
    semiperimeter = sum(t) / 2
    return all(semiperimeter > u for u in t)

def prompt_input(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            s = input(prompt)
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print(s, 'is not a number')

def triangle_demo():
    print('input the values')
    a = prompt_input('input side a: ')
    b = prompt_input('input side b: ')
    c = prompt_input('input side c: ')
    return is_triangle(a, b, c)

print(triangle_demo())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test for a possible triangle is wrong. To assert that a triangle can be formed, you need to ensure that the shortest edge is longer than (or equal to) the difference of the other two.

```
def is_triangle(a, b, c):
    d, e, f = sorted([a, b, c])
    return f - e <=  d

a, b, c = 10, 12, 20
print(is_triangle(a, b, c))   # True

a, b, c = 10, 12, 44
print(is_triangle(a, b, c))   # False
```

Another, more trivial issue in your code is that the input of your values must be converted to numbers:

```
side = float(input('enter a side length'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the output from `input()` to an `int` (you had it the wrong way around):

```
try:
    ans = int(input(prompt))
    return ans
```

As an aside, the logic within `is_triangle` doesn't match the logic you described in your question, but that is another issue altogether, and one I think you can work out.